# How to send chat to a specific user in .Net using WebSocket?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, websocket

I want to send a message to a user based on their userId. How can this be done?

I tried it using http but the page has to be reloaded for the messages to appear. I've read that this can be done using Real time communication Protocols like WebSockets. How can this be implemented in .Net?

Comment: You may want to take a look at signalR for your real time communication needs. In this way you can add clients to groups and send out messages to groups or just to the caller.
eg. Clients.Caller.SendAsync("eventName", eventData) will only push that event to the caller.
For sending to a group of clients,
await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "roomName");
await Clients.Group("roomName").SendAsync("JoinedLobby", userName);

Comment: yes, asp.net core signalr, here's the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: then send to specific user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-8.0#users-in-signalr